# Create an xpage (order form) in a nice format from the web (in a pdf) and mail it to customer

Tags: xpages, developer-tools

I need to send a customer's order to them in a pdf file but formatted like you would format a form in the Notes client.  So a salesman create the order through a browser and clicks a button to send the order to the customer.  It needs to create the order in a nice format like the Notes client would, attach it to a mail message and open the message for the salesman to add text.  Has anyone done this?  How do you do it?

I also need to do the same thing but instead of creating a pdf, take a product graphic attachment from the Notes document, attach it to a mail message and open the message for the user to add text for the customer.

Comment: For the first part of your question: a possible solution would be to markup the order form in the proper format/design in the browser, then send the generated HTML/ CSS to wkhtmltopdf: a program that you can install on your server to generate a PDF file from HTML. For both parts (if I understand the 2nd question correctly): have a look at this (https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter) to generate a mail with an embedded image/ attached file.

Comment: I just did a NotesIn9 video demonstration of populating a PDF form from XPages. Sounds like that might help with part of your wish list here. It was 195. http://www.notesin9.com/2016/08/25/notesin9-195-use-xpages-to-fill-a-pdf-form/

Comment: David, I tried viewing your #1 and #2 for PDFs both on your notesin9 and xpages.tv sites and they wouldn't run.  I tried in FF, IE and Chrome.

Comment: My input xpage doesn't look like an official invoice for printing.  Would I have to create a separate xpages only for printing?  Is there a way to run the PDF conversion and email in script in the background?  Do you know anything about DominoPDF?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the POI4XPages project in OpenNTF. It will allow you to create a template in Word, populate "fields" in the Word doc from XPages and then when the user clicks the button it can fill in those fields and be downloaded as a pdf file or a Word file. Then the user could modify/add a message and attach to their email.

Or, you could have them enter the message in your XPage app and populate the Word doc with the message and create the pdf file to download.

Howard

Comment: Here is the answer for everyone looking to do this in a simple way in Lotuscript or Javascript.  DominoPDF is a download you can get with a DLL.  Declare the DLL library in your code and then it's a two line call with tremendous flexibility in creating the PDF.  In the background and from an xPage I run an agent that creates the PDF on the disk of wherever it's running, then emails a message with PDF attached.  Even though the Notes form says to use the xpage, this routine prints the form as in the Notes client so you format the form as you would in the client to make it fancy (and quick/easy)